# Pass command line options to guile via geiser

Tags: emacs, guile, geiser

Geiser can be configured to read ~/.guile when running Guile from within Emacs. I would like to append command line options to the argument list passed to guile.

Is there a variable that holds the command line options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize `geiser-guile-binary` to a list of strings (change the "Value" button to "repeat").  The first one should be "guile" (or whatever the binary for guile is on your system) and the next entries should be strings each containing one argument.

You can double check it by putting `(insert (pp (geiser-guile--parameters)))` in a scheme file with geiser loaded and then running M-x `eval-last-sexp`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I disabled

;;(use-modules (ice-9 colorized))
;;(activate-colorized)

in my ~/.guile-geiser file the problem disappeared.

readline is also not needed within Emacs, just press C-up/down to see the history.

;;(use-modules (ice-9 readline))
;;(activate-readline)